# How to filter and read each item in array

Tags: c#

Below is the sample Json which I receive in my Service Bus queue. I would like to filter out each item that they contain DocType and ProjectId property before doing any further processing. Below array contains three items and of these only two has DocType and ProjectId, so I would like validation to get only these 2 items, how can I do it?

MySbMsg:

```
    [
    {
        "Id": "Test1",
        "DocType": "Test",
        "Project": "Test1",
        "ProjectId": "tab12",
        "Tags": [],
        "Properties": {},
        "Categories": [],
        "Trigger": true,
        "Received": "2020-12-16T13:43:50.3001244Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "test2",
        "DocType": "Test",
        "Project": "Test2",
        "ProjectId": "tab123",
        "Tags": [],
        "Properties": {},
        "Categories": [],
        "Trigger": true,
        "Received": "2020-12-18T13:43:50.3001244Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "test3",
        "Project": "Test3",
        "ProjectId": "tab1232",
        "Tags": [],
        "Properties": {},
        "Categories": [],
        "Trigger": true,
        "Received": "2020-12-28T13:43:50.3001244Z"
    }
]
```

C# code:

```
 public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topicname", "subscriptionname", Connection = "AzureServiceBusString")] string mySbMsg, ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
           
            List<Document> lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Document>>(mySbMsg);
}
```

Comment: Where is the bug?

Comment: what do you mean? I am unable to filter out the items. i would like to filter out the items having these two properties. I tried lists[0] but that doesnt work out

Comment: 'Validation' usually means "if X is not true, an error has occured and need to be handled". It seems like you are asking to filter a list according to some condition. See [linq .Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0)

Comment: That's right I am looking for filtering rather than validating. Sorry for my noob explanation. I will change that

Comment: @AnkitKumar as @JonasH mentioned, you should be using where linq operation like  `lists.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DocType) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.ProjectId))`

Comment: Can you please post it in detail as an answer. It will be easy for me to test and mark it as an answer

Comment: also i am more looking to check if the items contain these property, rather than values. If my items contain DocType and ProjectId as key and no values, I would like to have that value.in above you are checking the value of the these properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you need to use `linq`'s `where` method to filter out those records which has no `DocType` and `ProjectId` in the service bus message payload.

```
lists  = lists.Where(l => 
                          !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.DocType) 
                          && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.ProjectId)
                     )
                     .ToList();
```

And to check if these properties exist or not in payload then you can use below query:

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse(mySbMsg);
var lists = jArray.Where(j => j["DocType"] != null && j["ProjectId"] != null)
                  .Select(j => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(j.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: i am looking to check if the items contain these property, rather than values. If my items contain DocType and ProjectId as key and no values, I would like to have that item.in above you are checking the value of the these properties

Comment: @AnkitKumar - Use `JArray` for that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: but here we are putting it as a lists. if I just want mySBMsg here omitting the items I dont need.Sorry for confusion but the line List<Document> lists = JsonConvert... was just something I was trying . i am more interested in the mySBMsg after filtering

Comment: Is it not filtering those records which are not having property? What do you want --- do you want those records which has relevant properties or those which are not having properties?

Comment: it is but now we have an IEnumerable type

Comment: Add `.ToList()` at the end that will convert to List as you require.

Comment: i want both, but what i am looking is to have them as an array as it is now.

Comment: one array with items with the properties and other without those properties

Comment: , I mean serializing it back to the structure as of mySbMsg

Comment: If you want Array then use `ToArray`. If you have the first list which you require and other list with all items then I believe you can find the diff items too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228202/discussion-between-ankit-kumar-and-user1672994).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach wul dbe to use the Reflection.

Just use the C# Reflection on your type and check if the property exist or not.

```
Obj.GetType().GetProperty(name)!=null
```

Comment: but how do you go for each item here in mySbMsg

Comment: Define a Predicate<T> and use that to filter your collection.

Comment: can you please edit and provide the answer in details. if I do mySbMsg.GetType().GetPropert("DocType")... it gives me null value

Answer (score 0):

```
var withDocAndProjectId = lists.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.DocType) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProjectId))
```

Comment: you are checking if DocType is null or empty, whereas I would like to check if my Sbmsg has these properties, it doesnt matter if the properties don't have values.

Comment: Your deserialising into an object which I imagine will have 2 properties with nullable types.

Comment: lets forget the code with deserializing line. I was trying to figure out a way and so I wrote that. how can I go from MySbMsg